# Ubuntu 18.04 desktop frozen after login (mouse doesn't move, keyboard unresponsive)

Tags: 18.04

My three months old laptop is suddenly showing a weird problem. The desktop hangs right after login: the mouse pointer doesn't move, and the keyboard is unresponsive (can't open Activities menu, nor console with Ctrl-Alt-F3). The system is still responsive otherwise: I can SSH into it, kill the `systemd` process for the user that just logged in and the laptop goes back to the login screen, and keyboard and mouse are responsive again.

The problem started after I installed the GNOME System Monitor Shell Extension. I then removed it, but the problem persists. What else can I try?

EDIT (info requested by heynnema):

`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` doesn't exist (only `application_state` and `notifications` exist under `~/.local/share/gnome-shell`)

`/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  3 12:25 system76-power@system76.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  9  2019 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  9  2019 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

EDIT 2: (followup questions by heynnema)

```
free -h:

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62G        487M         61G        105M        814M         61G
Swap:          4.0G          0B        4.0G

sysctl vm.swappiness:

vm.swappiness = 60
```

Comment: Boot into your account, using whatever tricks required, and edit your question with the output of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema done. Does it say anything to you?

Comment: Yes, it may. It says that either: 1) you're running Pop_OS and not Ubuntu, or 2) you're running on a System 76 which is not Ubuntu, or 3) you've manually installed system76-power@system76.com GNOME extension, or 4) you're running system76-power@system76.com along with some other utility like TLP. Which one is correct? Try going to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable system76-power, and see if it helps.

Comment: @heynnema The laptop is indeed a System 76 with Ubuntu 18.04 (factory pre-installed, with some System 76 extensions and tools). Since I can't login to the UI I moved the `system76-power@system76.com` folder out of the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` folder, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Did you either restart GNOME Shell, or reboot, after removing system76-power? Do you have TLP installed? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: @heynnema I rebooted the system after moving the `system76-power@system76.com` folder out of the way. `dpkg -s tlp` says that TLP is not installed. I've updated the question with the output of `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: Try logging into a different account and see if the problem exists there.

Comment: @heynnema tried that already. It affects all user accounts. I booted the laptop with a Ubuntu 18.04 Live USB, and everything works fine, so I'm leaning toward ruling out hardware issues. I'm seriously puzzled.

Comment: What video card make/model, and what version video driver? Do you know how to boot with nomodeset? And show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me make/model # of computer.

Comment: The laptop is a System76 Oryx Pro with a GeForce RTX 2080. I'm using the Nvidia driver version 440.44. I was able to boot with nomodeset, but the laptop screen is totally blank (is it expected?). Anyway, I can still SSH into it and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` says `1.07.09-1`

Comment: Please check my preliminary answer. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Please show me `sudo lshw -C memory`. What speed is your memory clocked at?

Comment: @heynnema I was able to solve the problem thanks to your pointing me in the right direction. I'll write an answer to document the solution.

Comment: @heynnema please check my answer below. If you update your solution, I'll be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nvidia**

You have Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 with driver 440.44. The current is 440.64 and can be downloaded from https://www.geforce.com/drivers

**Memory**

Make sure that your 64G memory is clocked at 2666 MHz.

**BIOS**

You have BIOS 1.07.09-1. The System76 web pages don't call out specific BIOS versions, but rather, have BIOS check/update page at https://support.system76.com/articles/system-firmware/

**Update #1:**

The user ended up reinstalling the kernel and Nvidia drivers using the System76 repos, and it's all working now.