# Ubuntu 18.04 mouse behaves weird after login

Tags: login, mouse

When I start Ubuntu and before login the mouse behaves normally. After login the mouse behaves weird. I can move the mouse in just a tiny area after stopping the movement the mouse pulls to the middle of that small area. The keyboard behave (as far as I can see) normally. I did not take any specific actions, like installing or configuration software, before this weird behavior started.

What I tried:
Login in as a different user makes no difference. Switching to another mouse makes no difference. Unplugging the mouse before login and plugging it in after does not make any difference.

I searched on Ask Ubuntu and the closest I came was: [Ubuntu 18.04 desktop frozen after login (mouse doesn't move, keyboard unresponsive)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214302/ubuntu-18-04-desktop-frozen-after-login-mouse-doesnt-move-keyboard-unresponsi)  The behavior here is quite different.

Comment: Try reinstalling the mouse driver.

Comment: Because I waited a log time, Ubuntu ask me to update. I did, but no difference. I waited longer, and was ask to Upgrade to 20.04. I did. Bu tno difference. I assume this upgrade to 20.04 was also a upgrade of the mouse driver.

Comment: And it is, in the GUI for me impossible to reinstall the mouser driver, because ... I can not use the mouse. By the way, the mouse is correctly installed, because before login, I can normally use it. After login the use of the mouse get corrupted.

Comment: Do ```sudo do-release-upgrade``` to upgrade. if not try upgrading again. The newer kernel should have better patches for your system.

Comment: Rebooting again solved the problem. So it was indeed the update /upgrade. Comments given in this thread helped my to give a direction to the solution. I would like to marked this as solved. I could answer and solve my own question. But I feel then the value of the contributes who helped me is lost.

Answer (score 1):

The update and upgrade to 20.04 and an extra reboot solved the problem. Thanks to all who contribute to come to this solution.